# 'Union' of maps

Tags: functions, notation, definition

Let $f : A \to Y$, $g : B \to Y$. Suppose that $f(x) = g(x)$ whenever $x \in A \cap B$. Define

$$
h : A \cup B \to Y, \\
h(x) = \begin{cases}
f(x) & \text{ if $x \in A$} \\
g(x) & \text{ if $x \in B$}
\end{cases}.
$$

Is there a standard name or notation for combining two maps $f,g$ into a map $h$ in this manner?

Comment: A bump function?

Comment: There is the issue of the fact that your map $h$ may not actually be a function.  If $x$ lies in both $A$ and $B$, and $f(x)\neq g(x)$, then what is $h(x)$?  One way to correct this is to take the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$.  Then $h(x)$ is the coproduct of two maps (though there are other maps that might be called the 'coproduct' of two maps).

Comment: @Hayden: "Suppose that $f(x) = g(x)$ whenever $x \in A \cap B$."

Comment: @Snowball My bad for not reading closely enough.  Hopefully the coproduct part is useful though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In set theory, at least, writing $f\cup g$ is perfectly acceptable and well understood. I don't think I ever heard a name for that, though.